# How we can open the webcam using OpenCv and Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I installed OpenCV 4.1.2 and Xcode on my MacBook. 
My goal is to open the webcam with OpenCV.

The steps I followed I used this tutorial ([Tutorial I followed](https://medium.com/@jaskaranvirdi/setting-up-opencv-and-c-development-environment-in-xcode-b6027728003) ) :

- Set Head Search Paths
- Set library search paths
- I added the OpenCV framework in the hierarchy of my project

Like you can see on the following picture :
[image: Search path picture]

After that I coded :

```
#include "../opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv.hpp"
#include "../opencv2.framework/Headers/highgui.hpp"
#include "../opencv2.framework/Headers/core.hpp"
#include "../opencv2.framework/Headers/imgproc.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(){
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while(true){
        Mat Webcam;
        cap.read(Webcam);
        imshow("video de ma webcam", Webcam);
    }

}
```

Moreover the hierarchy of my project is like that 
[image: hierarchy of my project]

So when I am running my project I have this kind of errors

[image: errors picture]

Do you have any idea where this problem might be coming from?

What I tried to correct this problem :

- I tried to change the hierarchy of the Library Search Paths and Header Search Paths
- Uninstall and install again OpenCV
- Don't use directly the framework in the projet, only use this code line : 
  `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Comment: Since you have created a C++ project, you need to add the linker flags (example -lcv) for the libraries used.

Comment: and how do I know which flags I need to add please ? @Totoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [this article](https://medium.com/@jaskaranvirdi/setting-up-opencv-and-c-development-environment-in-xcode-b6027728003) as a guideline; it includes the pkg-config command that shows you the library files to be added (you don't have to add all of them, but the easier way out is to add all).